# Passing method to method in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I have faced with a problem of passing method to method in C++. What I am trying to do is to reduce amount of code, which is almost the same for several methods.

For example, I have next code:

```
class F_test {
public: 
    void f1() {
        std::cout << "f1" << std::endl;
    }

    void f2() {
        std::cout << "f2" << std::endl;
    }

    void foo_main(std::string str, std::function<void(void)> const &f) {
        std::cout << "some actions before" << std::endl;
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
        f();
        std::cout << "some actions after" << std::endl;
    }

    void f1(std::string s1) {
        std::function <void(void)> m1 = F_test::f1;
        foo_main("processing f1", m1);
    }

    void f2(std::string s2) {
        std::function <void(void)> m2 = F_test::f2;
        foo_main("processing f2", m2);
    }
};
```

As for processing **f1** and **f2** methods I need to perform some the same operations, I have decided to created one method (**foo_main**) with these operations and pass needed function (f1 or f2) to it, rather than create two separate methods with code duplication.

But, these code is failed on compilation with:

> 'F_test::f1': function call missing argument list; use '&F_test::f1' to create a pointer to member
>   'F_test::f2': function call missing argument list; use '&F_test::f2' to create a pointer to member

If to write **&F_test::f1** and **&F_test::f2**, another compilation error is happened:

> 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,>::_Set(std::_Func_base<_Ret,> *)' : cannot convert argument 1 from '_Myimpl *' to 'std::_Func_base<_Ret,> *'

Comment: Thanks for help! Using std::bind or lambda solves the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-static member functions need an object to be called with. You can't just call `f1()` without an instance of `F_test`. The compile error results from you trying to do that.

To create a null ary function out of member function, you need to *bind* an instance to it, whether via `std::bind`:

```
std::function <void()> m1 = std::bind(&F_test::f1, this);
```

or a lambda:

```
 std::function <void()> m1 = [this]{ f1(); };
```

---

Note that `bind` doesn't work in this case since you have overloaded the name `f1`. It would work in the general case though. The lambda will work regardless.

Comment: `&F_test::f1` would be ambiguous here, Have to use something like `static_cast<void (F_test::*)()>(&F_test::f1)`

Comment: @Jarod42 Ah, yeah, didn't realize OP had two different `f1`s.

Answer (score 1):

The simpler would be to use lambda:

```
F_test test;

test.foo_process("string", [&](){test.f1();});
```

Else to select (in `std::bind`) overload `f1()` whereas other overloads exist (as `f1(std::string)`), you have to specify which one you want:

```
static_cast<void (F_test::*)()>(&F_test::f1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use lambda by some reasons, then you should rewrite the code like:

```
class F_test {
public:
  void f1impl() const {
    std::cout << "f1" << std::endl;
  }

  void f2impl() const {
    std::cout << "f2" << std::endl;
  }

  void foo_process(std::string str, std::function<void(const F_test&)> const &f) {
    std::cout << "some actions before" << std::endl;
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    f(*this);
    std::cout << "some actions after" << std::endl;
  }

  void f1(std::string s1) {
    std::function<void(const F_test&)> f = &F_test::f1impl;
    foo_process("processing f1", f);
  }

  void f2(std::string s2) {
    std::function <void(const F_test&)> m2 = &F_test::f2impl;
    foo_process("processing f2", m2);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't use a member function pointer to initialize a std::function. Use a lambda instead.

```
void f1(std::string s1) {
    auto m1 = [this](){ f1(); };
    foo_main("processing f1", m1);
}
```